# Can't connect to WiFi with USB adapter

Tags: wifi, drivers, usb, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

On an old 32 bit system with an up-to-date Debian Buster I wanted to use a WiFi USB adapter. I bought this adapter based on a recommendation on this [German Debian site](https://wiki.debianforum.de/WLAN_Einrichten#unter_Debian_GNU.2FLinux_getestet:). It can scan for networks but I cannot connect to any WPA2 network. The correct passphrase is given and still it asks for the password after trying to connect all the time. So maybe it is a wpa_supplicant issue. Here are a few details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 4.19.0-14-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) i686 GNU/Linux

$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter   <--- THIS
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So it is an RTL8191SU chipset which should work with the `firmware-realtek` package from Debian. I installed it. At first I tried to use the adapter with the installed wicd. This was not working correctly, so I switched to network-manager.

A few relevant parts of `journalctl -ax`:

```
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: usb 1-1.4: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: usb 1-1.4: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_exit [i915])
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: usb 1-1.4: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x000a
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: usb 1-1.4: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 24:05:0f:dd:35:76
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: usb 1-1.4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver r8712u
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: usb 1-1.4: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname systemd-udevd[275]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Mär 03 15:50:38 hostname kernel: r8712u 1-1.4:1.0 wlx24050fdd3576: renamed from wlan0
```

The result of `journalctl -axu NetworkManager` before trying to connect:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-03-04 09:54:25 CET, end at Thu 2021-03-04 10:46:51 CET. --
Mär 04 09:54:31 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 76.
Mär 04 09:54:35 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848075.9203] NetworkManager (version 1.14.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Mär 04 09:54:35 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848075.9204] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: no-mac-addr-change.conf)
Mär 04 09:54:36 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848076.2232] wifi-wext: (wlx24050fdd3576): driver does not support SSID scans (scan_capa 0x00).
Mär 04 09:54:36 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848076.2233] wifi-wext: (wlx24050fdd3576): using WEXT for WiFi device control
Mär 04 09:54:36 hostname systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 76.
Mär 04 09:54:36 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848076.2297] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Mär 04 09:54:36 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848076.3203] manager[0x26e9038]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Mär 04 09:54:36 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848076.3203] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Mär 04 09:54:37 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848077.0720] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Mär 04 09:54:37 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848077.0720] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "hostname"
Mär 04 09:54:37 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848077.0722] dns-mgr[0x26db4a0]: init: dns=default, rc-manager=resolvconf
Mär 04 09:54:37 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848077.0725] manager[0x26e9038]: rfkill: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Mär 04 09:54:37 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848077.0725] manager[0x26e9038]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.0840] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.0840] ifupdown:       interface-parser: source line includes interfaces file(s) /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <warn>  [1614848078.0841] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces.d/* doesn't exist
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.0841] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.0841] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.0841] settings: Loaded settings plugin: SettingsPluginIfupdown ("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.14.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.0842] settings: Loaded settings plugin: NMSKeyfilePlugin (internal)
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.2960] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SSID.nmconnection (0194e1d3-b525-4b74-8a31-3641f6f412ed,"SSID")
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.3909] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.3910] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.3911] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.3912] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.6583] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.14.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Mär 04 09:54:38 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848078.9711] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.14.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.1616] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.14.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.2550] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.14.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3329] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.14.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3550] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3554] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3569] manager: (enp5s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3595] keyfile: add connection /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1.nmconnection (12422369-d18d-3170-bb09-9ddc97371a9f,"Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1")
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3601] settings: (enp5s0): created default wired connection 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1'
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3607] device (enp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3619] device (enp5s0): carrier: link connected
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3654] manager: (wlx24050fdd3576): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Mär 04 09:54:39 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848079.3665] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.6730] device (enp5s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.6739] policy: auto-activating connection 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1' (12422369-d18d-3170-bb09-9ddc97371a9f)
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.6751] device (enp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1' (12422369-d18d-3170-bb09-9ddc97371a9f)
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.6755] device (enp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.6760] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.6764] device (enp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.6772] device (enp5s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.7001] dhcp4 (enp5s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.8463] dhcp4 (enp5s0): dhclient started with pid 443
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.9053] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.9054] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848081.9054] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.0366] sup-iface[0x26d15d8,wlx24050fdd3576]: supports 1 scan SSIDs
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.0374] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.0374] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname dhclient[443]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.55.90 on enp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname dhclient[443]: DHCPACK of 192.168.55.90 from 192.168.55.1
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2623] dhcp4 (enp5s0):   address 192.168.55.90
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2623] dhcp4 (enp5s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2624] dhcp4 (enp5s0):   gateway 192.168.55.1
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2624] dhcp4 (enp5s0):   lease time 3596400
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2624] dhcp4 (enp5s0):   hostname 'hostname'
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2624] dhcp4 (enp5s0):   nameserver '192.168.62.1'
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2624] dhcp4 (enp5s0):   domain name 'bsc'
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2625] dhcp4 (enp5s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2635] device (enp5s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2643] device (enp5s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2646] device (enp5s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.2652] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.3404] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.3406] policy: set 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1' (enp5s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname dhclient[443]: bound to 192.168.55.90 -- renewal in 1613329 seconds.
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.4652] device (enp5s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Mär 04 09:54:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848082.4659] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Mär 04 09:54:52 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614848092.0587] manager: startup complete
```

Also, to let network-manager manage all connections, I edited my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

There are no additional files in the included directory. I followed the advice from https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse and edited my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` as follows:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

The maybe best bet is wpa_supplicant, here are more details before trying to connect:

```
$ journalctl -axu wpa_supplicant
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-03-04 09:54:25 CET, end at Thu 2021-03-04 10:54:00 CET. --
Mär 04 09:54:31 hostname systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
-- Subject: A start job for unit wpa_supplicant.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit wpa_supplicant.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 71.
Mär 04 09:54:34 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Mär 04 09:54:34 hostname systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
-- Subject: A start job for unit wpa_supplicant.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit wpa_supplicant.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 71.
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx24050fdd3576 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mär 04 09:54:41 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: rfkill: Cannot get wiphy information
```

I tried to google for this "Driver does not support authentication..." but couldn't find something really useful.

When trying to connect to the wifi, this is added to the network-manager journal:

```
Mär 04 10:56:42 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851802.3785] agent-manager: req[0x2748a50, :1.59/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7544] device (wlx24050fdd3576): Activation: starting connection 'SSID' (0194e1d3-b525-4b74-8a31-3641f6f412ed)
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7548] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="0194e1d3-b525-4b74-8a31-3641f6f412ed" name="SSID" pid=847 uid=1000 result="success"
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7550] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7566] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7569] device (wlx24050fdd3576): Activation: (wifi) access point 'SSID' has security, but secrets are required.
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7569] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7595] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7619] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7625] device (wlx24050fdd3576): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SSID' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7626] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SSID'
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7626] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7626] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7626] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7626] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mär 04 10:56:55 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851815.7626] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Mär 04 10:56:59 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851819.7816] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: ready -> scanning
Mär 04 10:57:09 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851829.7852] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Mär 04 10:57:10 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851830.2315] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Mär 04 10:57:20 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <warn>  [1614851840.2282] sup-iface[0x26d15d8,wlx24050fdd3576]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Mär 04 10:57:20 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851840.2294] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Mär 04 10:57:20 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851840.3330] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mär 04 10:57:21 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <warn>  [1614851841.3445] device (wlx24050fdd3576): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Mär 04 10:57:21 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851841.3445] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 10:57:21 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <warn>  [1614851841.3465] device (wlx24050fdd3576): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Mär 04 10:57:30 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851850.3345] device (wlx24050fdd3576): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Mär 04 10:59:21 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <warn>  [1614851961.3556] device (wlx24050fdd3576): No agents were available for this request.
Mär 04 10:59:21 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851961.3556] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 04 10:59:21 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <warn>  [1614851961.3567] device (wlx24050fdd3576): Activation: failed for connection 'SSID'
Mär 04 10:59:21 hostname NetworkManager[350]: <info>  [1614851961.3572] device (wlx24050fdd3576): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

And the wpa_supplicant journal:

```
Mär 04 10:57:09 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: wlx24050fdd3576: Trying to associate with 06:da:88:10:73:7d (SSID='SSID' freq=2437 MHz)
Mär 04 10:57:09 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: Failed to add supported operating classes IE
Mär 04 10:57:09 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: wlx24050fdd3576: Association request to the driver failed
Mär 04 10:57:10 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: wlx24050fdd3576: Associated with 06:da:88:10:73:7d
Mär 04 10:57:20 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: wlx24050fdd3576: Authentication with 06:da:88:10:73:7d timed out.
Mär 04 10:57:20 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: wlx24050fdd3576: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=06:da:88:10:73:7d reason=3 locally_generated=1
Mär 04 10:57:20 hostname wpa_supplicant[351]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/1
```